# Powershell download files with today's date from FTP server

Tags: powershell, ftp

```
$today = (get-date).Date  


$dateStr = '{0:yyyyMMdd}' -f $today

New-Item C:\Desktop\test_$dateStr -ItemType directory 

ftp
open
Server Name
UserID
Password
dir
lcd C:\Desktop\test_$dateStr
prompt
binary
mget *$dateStr.txt   
mget *$dateStr.zip  
bye
```

I am try to download today's txt files and zip files from FTP server. 
The files are named test_20131001 so I set up as `$dateStr` but it is not working.
FTP server can not find the folder that I create before I enter FTP server.
`lcd C:\Desktop\test_$dateStr` does not work...

Comment: You create the directory without *IPREO* but want to lcd to the directory with IPREO? Typo?

Comment: Sorry typo... Thanks for notice :)

Comment: I would suggest that instead of trying to automate ftp.exe, use the [`FtpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx) .NET class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lcd` and `mget` are interpreted by FTP.exe, not PowerShell. FTP.exe isn't going to understand `$dateStr`.  Take a look at this [FTPClient module](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-FTP-Client-db6fe0cb) as one way to automate FTP download in PowerShell.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)
could you tell me what is the command for $dateStr in FTPClinent?

Comment: There is no command per se, you just specify $dateStr as part of the path and since the FTP command is a PowerShell command it will get the expanded string value.